# How to check if a field from a form is filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I am trying to figure out a way to blank a field if a particular field is entered and vice versa.

The form locates urgent care locations base on the entries that the users enters. So we have the urgent care facility name, city, zip code and miles field.

So what I would like to do is if the user enters the zip code in the zip code field and if the user previously had selected a city based on the selection given, it blanks out the city and vice versa. If the user selects a city from the city drop down list, the zip code field blanks out.

The following is the code I have:

```js
$('#zip').on('input‌', function() { $('#city').val("") })
$('#city').on('input‌', function() { $('#zip').val("") })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate="" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="urgentcare" ng-model="searchParam.UrgentCareName" placeholder="Urgent Care Name" type="text" />
      </div>
      <!---<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="urgentcare" name="Urgent Care Name" onblur="if(this.value === '') this.value = 'Urgent Care Name';" onfocus="if(this.value === 'Urgent Care Name') this.value = '';" type="text" value="Urgent Care Name" /></div>--->

      <div class="form-group">
        <!---<select class="form-control margin-bottom1" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City" ng-options="City.value for City in Cities">
            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option> </select>--->

        <SELECT name="proCity" class="form-control margin-bottom1" id="city" placeholder="City" ng-model="searchParam.City">
          <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>
          <cfoutput query="UCarecityFind">
            <option value=#officecity#>#officecity#</option>
          </cfoutput>
        </select>

      </div>
      <hr />
      <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <!---<select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles"></select>--->

              <select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.distance">
                <option selected="selected" value=" "></option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>15</option>
                <option>20</option>
              </select>
              <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#zip').on('input', function() { $('#city').val("") })`

Comment: @adeneo I am new to jquery and would like if you can please how your function works

Comment: @RobertoFlores The `input` event runs when the user types something into an input field. So when they type in the `zip` field, it executes that function, which empties the value of the `city` field. Do the same thing for the reverse direction.

Comment: @Barmar Okay that is what I figured and that is what I did after looking at it for a while. However, it does not blank the field when I enter the zip code and vice versa

Comment: You're missing the `$` in `$('#city')` and `$('#zip')`. See the error messages in the Javascript console.

Comment: There's no `id="city"` in your HTML, you have that `<select>` commented out. The city menu is `<select name="proCity"`, but it doesn't have an `id`.

Comment: You also seem to have an invisible character at the end of `'input'`

Comment: Your snippet doesn't load jQuery.

Comment: @Barmar Hello, I have added the city id back and it still doesnt work corrrectly. You are right it doesnt load Jquery, I would like it to be jquery or javascript

Comment: You're still missing `$` in `$("#city").on` and `$("#zip").on`

Comment: @Barmar No they are their.

Comment: @Barmar How would I translate the jquery into javascript? I am thinking it is conflicting with the angular framework

Comment: Use `document.querySelector("selector")` instead of `$("selector")` and `.addEventListener()` instead of `.on()`.

Comment: But I think lots of people use Angular with jQuery, I don't think they conflict.

Comment: You haven't loaded Angular into the stack snippet, how can they be conflicting?

Comment: @Barmar You are correct but I loaded Angular on my end and it appears to not work. I have also made the adjustments to javascript and it still appears to no clear either fields

Comment: But since it doesn't work in the stack snippet you've posted here, that's irrelvant.

Comment: @Barmar yes you are correct it is irrelvant

Comment: You still have an extra, invisible character after `input` in `$('#city').on('input', ...)`. It's Unicode character `0x5396c`

Comment: Okay. will I removed it and it still appears. Just going to see how to remove it some other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invisible character with code `0x5396c` after `input` in your `.on()` calls. When I remove that, the code works.

```js
$('#zip').on('input', function() {
  $('#city').val("")
})
$('#city').on('input', function() {
  $('#zip').val("")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate="" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="urgentcare" ng-model="searchParam.UrgentCareName" placeholder="Urgent Care Name" type="text" />
      </div>
      <!---<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="urgentcare" name="Urgent Care Name" onblur="if(this.value === '') this.value = 'Urgent Care Name';" onfocus="if(this.value === 'Urgent Care Name') this.value = '';" type="text" value="Urgent Care Name" /></div>--->

      <div class="form-group">
        <!---<select class="form-control margin-bottom1" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City" ng-options="City.value for City in Cities">
            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option> </select>--->

        <SELECT name="proCity" class="form-control margin-bottom1" id="city" placeholder="City" ng-model="searchParam.City">
          <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>
          <cfoutput query="UCarecityFind">
            <option value=#officecity#>#officecity#</option>
          </cfoutput>
        </select>

      </div>
      <hr />
      <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <!---<select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles"></select>--->

              <select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.distance">
                <option selected="selected" value=" "></option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>15</option>
                <option>20</option>
              </select>
              <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you remove the hidden character?

Comment: I put my cursor on the quote, and pressed the Backspace key.

Comment: I tried that  and I pasted it in my file and it still doesnt appear to work

Comment: Then just retype it from scratch. I don't know where that character came from, I just know that it's there, you need to get rid of it.

Comment: I even tried Notepad++ to remove the hidden character and nothing

Comment: I saw it when I looked at the source code in the Chrome debugger. It showed it as a little dot between the `t` and `'`.

Comment: Rewrote and and still the same thing. :(

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you. I have no idea what that character is, or what would cause it to appear in your code.